# Will I get the kill if my tank wreck destroys another tank?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I'm wondering if I can get the kill in the following situation:

> I drive off a bridge and fall on an enemy tank. Both survive the crash and both are losing HP continuously. But he has more HP than me, so I die 1 second before he do.

I haven't had any chance to test this myself as most times I am playing SPGs.

---

Here's a video that shows a similar situation (at 4:30):

Did the wrecked tank get the kill?

Comment: I don't know if you get them, but if you drop kick a tank with your tank, you _deserve_ the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they die within a few seconds of you. you get the kill, if not. then its a suicide for them.

At least judging by the game's kill mechanics thats how it "should" work.

for example. if you track someone while they are in deep water, you get the kill for drowning them. or if you shoot someone near a cliff and they drive off and die, you get the kill. Instead of it being a suicide for them.

A similar situation has happened to me on a rare occasion where I crashed into someone's bum and lit them on fire, but I killed myself (which the enemy got the kill credit for). they died by fire and I got the kill from the grave. (proves killing from grave is possible)

I believe the ruling is somewhere within 10 seconds of damage(probably <5). Tracking them INTO deep water (as tanks sometimes spin out when you track them) will give them a suicide.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mentioned the game's kill mechanics, but I can't find any information about the kill mechanics on WoT website or via Google. Can you please tell me where did you read about the kill mechanics?

Comment: the kill mechanics are from my personal experiences, you can test them out yourself by doing a training room 1v1 with a friend.